# Google Maps - Show multiple markers with the current location marker style

Tags: android, google-maps

You're familiar with the current location marker style on maps, a circle blue marker which moves when you move. How can I have multiple markers like that on the map?

**Note:** I want to have multiple live markers. Imagine, I want to see where my family are going. Then, is it possible to show the route between my current location and the other family member location?

**Note:** Telegram done that on the live location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any drawable on marker.

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.anyDrawable)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .icon(icon);

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```